# Powershell script to send mail with embedded pictures (under exchange server)

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server-2007

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to send mails over an Exchange server with embedded pictures:

```
Start-Process Outlook
$file1='C:\ScreenShots\file1.png'
$file2='C:\ScreenShots\file2.png'

$textBody=""<html>Hello, <br /> <br /> Here are the pictures : <br /> <br /><br   /><tr><td> <img src='$file1'> </img> <br /> <br /></img><img src='$file2'> </img>    </td></tr></table></html>";
$Outlook = New-Object -comObject  Outlook.Application 

$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
$Mail.Recipients.Add("myself@gmail.com") 
$Mail.Subject = "Pictures"
$Mail.HTMLBody= $textBody
$mail.Send()
```

The mail is sent but the pictures are only available if sent the mail to myself.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hi guys,

Thanks for your advises, Instead of using a webservice, I have a network folder that's available for everyone.

Everyting is working fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

The file paths you specified are on the local filesystem. If you send it to someone else, and they do not have these file paths present on their system, then they will not appear correctly in Outlook.

Comment: Hello Trevor, Thanks for your answer. I'm looking for a method that sends the pictures with the mail. Do you have one?

Comment: @Deri Upload the images to the internet and use that URL instead of your local file system.

Comment: There are free services like Imgur that allow you to upload pictures. You can then copy the URLs from there and include them in your e-mails, as Hyper Anthony alluded to. Alternatively, you could host them on your own, public webserver.